# clip-path with SVG from external file

Tags: css, svg, shapes, clip-path

I'm playing around with SVG and wanted to see if I could store the SVG in an external file and call on it with `url(link)`, since FireFox doesn't support clip-path when declaring the shape in CSS.

However, the clipping doesn't work at all when linking to an external file.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zs05sm0/1/) with the SVG included and referenced to in the same document.

```
<img src="http://sarasoueidan.com/demos/css-svg-clipping/html-img-clipped-with-css-svg-clippath/flowers.jpg" style="clip-path: url(#svgPath); -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath)" />

<svg height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="svgPath">
            <path  stroke-width="1.5794" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M215,100.3c97.8-32.6,90.5-71.9,336-77.6
        c92.4-2.1,98.1,81.6,121.8,116.4c101.7,149.9,53.5,155.9,14.7,178c-96.4,54.9,5.4,269-257,115.1c-57-33.5-203,46.3-263.7,20.1
        c-33.5-14.5-132.5-45.5-95-111.1C125.9,246.6,98.6,139.1,215,100.3z"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

But when I include it while it's hosted on my server, it doesn't work. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zs05sm0/).

```
<img src="http://sarasoueidan.com/demos/css-svg-clipping/html-img-clipped-with-css-svg-clippath/flowers.jpg" style="clip-path: url(rvervuurt.com/svg.html#svgPath); -webkit-clip-path: url(rvervuurt.com/svg.html/#svgPath)" />
```

I don't see what the difference is between `url(#svgPath)` and `url(external.com/#svgPath)` in this case. Should it be included in a different way?

**Update:** I have tried adding it as an `.svg` file, but it doesn't seem to work. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zs05sm0/2/). Can someone check the .svg? The shape looks like it should in Illustrator.

Comment: Not sure but could be a CORS problem, or that the url should point to svg, and not html

Comment: @Amit I've tried a file with and without  `<clipPath>`, but it doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/2zs05sm0/2/

Comment: Needs to be an SVG file served as image/svg+xml and not an html file.

Comment: Yes but the clip-path property doesn't point to a clipPath element which it must to to be valid.

Comment: @RobertLongson How would a file need to look like? It isn't working with this one: http://rvervuurt.com/hexagon.svg#hexagon (see source)